# Excecuting script running ssh commands in the background

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, tty

I'm trying to execute this script on a remote server with `requiretty` enabled in the sudoers file.

```
#!/bin/bash

value=$(ssh -tt localhost sudo bash -c hostname)
echo $value
```

If I run the script using `$ ./sample.sh &` it stays stopped in the background. Only by using `fg` I can force the script to run. I think the problem is the missing tty for the output, but what can I do?

Comment: When exactly does the script get suspended? Does it get suspended before the `ssh` command runs? Does it get suspended when the `sudo` command runs? Does it get suspended when the `echo` built-in runs? Why run this script in the background anyway? You have to interact with the `sudo` command except under the strangest of circumstances...

Comment: I run multiple instances of the script in parallel, that's why I put it in the background. Some commands require sudo rights.

Comment: Can you make your own user account exempt from requiring to enter the `sudo` password when running those specific commands? That'd go a long way towards making this possible.

Comment: `sudo ssh localhost` doesn't make a lot of sense and `bash -c hostname` is really just `hostname` with a superfluous largish shell process needlessly wrapped around it. What are you trying to accomplish that just `hostname` does not deliver?

Answer (score 0):

> ... what can I do?

You can `stty -tostop`.